# What is the meaning of this code statement in verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

```
'define vend_a_drink {D,dispense,collect} = {IDLE, 2'b11}
```

D - next_state
dispense - dispense the drink
collect - collect coins
Given statement was included in a code written using verilog for an vending machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `` `vend_a_drink `` is present it is replaced with `{D,dispense,collect} = {IDLE, 2'b11}` during pre-compilation.